# $stmt->close() vs $stmt->free_result()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to clarify the difference between **$stmt->close()** and **$stmt->free_result()** when finalizing a prepared **mysqli** statement.

---

So far I use:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(host,user,password,database);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(sql statement);
[...]
$stmt->free_result();
$mysqli->close();
```

and everything seems to work fine.

But I've seen a lot of programmers use $stmt->close instead of $stmt->free_result(). And once I've seen both of them:

```
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

So what should I choose, under which circumstances and why?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`$stmt->free_result()` frees up memory related to a result set, whereas `$stmt->close()` frees up memory related to a prepared statement.  Subsequently calling `$stmt->close()` will cancel any result still remaining.

In essence, calling `$stmt->close()` will provide the same effect as calling `$stmt->free_result()` since it cancels the result set as well.  But calling `$stmt->free_result()` will not clear out the memory used by the prepared statement in which case you must use `$stmt->close()`.

As far as which one to use goes - there may be situations where you intend on using the prepared statement you have initialized, but are no longer in need of the result set you currently have.  In such a case you would wait on calling `$stmt->close()` until you are done with the prepared statement and instead call `$stmt->free_result()` before executing another statement.

Comment: ideal explanation!

Answer (score 5):

PHP will end your connection and free the resource after it finishes running;

[mysqli::close](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) **Closes a prepared statement.**

Since the number of total connections available is limited, freeing the resource the second you're done with it is a good practice.

And

[mysqli_stmt::free_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.free-result.php) **Frees stored result memory for the given statement handle.**

it's good practice to free explicitly the resource when you don't need them anymore. it might avoid make a heavy load into the server when many requests are made at the same time.

Both aren't never strictly necessary to invoke, and is a good practice the use of both.