# AJAX request via jQuery from PHP responses null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to receive data using AJAX from PHP which asks a database for some data. All i get from AJAX is `NULL`.

[image: received from Firefox Debugger]

When i alert the result (e.g. data.name) it says `undefined`.

HTML, AJAX and jQuery are in the `index.php` while PHP in `edit.php` is.

The AJAX request I use ...

```
$('div[data-toggle="edit"]').click(function() {
    var editid = $(this).attr('id').replace('edit','');
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: editid,
        dataType: 'JSON',
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#mainlabel').modal('show');
        $('input[name=add_name]').val(data.name);
        $('input[name=add_date]').val(data.date);
        $('input[name=add_image]').val(data.image);
        $('input[name=add_info]').val(data.info);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, message) {
        alert(message);
    });
});
```

... to receive data from this PHP code.

```
<?php
    require_once('main.conf');
    require_once('db.php');

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM datas d WHERE d.dataid = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET["editid"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $editname  = $row["name"];
        $editdate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row["date"]));
        $editimage  = $row["image"];
        $editinfo  = $row["additionalinfo"];
    }

    $return[] = array("name" => $editname,
                      "date" => $editdate,
                      "image" => $editimage,
                      "info" => $editinfo,
                      "getid" => $_GET["editid"]); //only for debugging

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

When i invoke the this code manually via `edit.php?editid=547` the JSON-result looks like it should.

```
0   
    name    "Mike Minus"
    date    "2015-05-12"
    image   "employee.jpg"
    info    "some additional info"
    getid   "547"
```

With the expected informations i want to fill some input-boxes.

```
<div class="modal-body mx-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="add_name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control validate" type="text" name="add_name" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="add_name" class="col-form-label">Datum:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="add_date" size="8" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="add_image" class="col-form-label">Bild:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="add_image" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="add_info" class="col-form-label">Zusatzinfos:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="add_info" value="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="edit" id="edit547">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
</div>
```

I know there are quite a lot of possible solutions in SO. Using `echo` instead of `return` in the PHP code, the appropriate `application/json` header or other techniques. Nothing could help till yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `$return[] = ...` (the square brackets).

Try `$return = ...`.

Those brackets are defining the variable as an array... Then you assing it another array.

The result is an array containing an array... The inner array will be json encoded, since the keys are not numeric. But the outer will not.

If you want to verify that, keep the square brackets and try the folowing ajax success callback:

```
.done(function(data) {
    $('#mainlabel').modal('show');
    $('input[name=add_name]').val(data[0].name);
    $('input[name=add_date]').val(data[0].date);
    $('input[name=add_image]').val(data[0].image);
    $('input[name=add_info]').val(data[0].info);
})
```

Notice the `[0]`... That is to access the first array element.

---

**EDIT**

For clarity, after comments... Try this:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$editname  = $row["name"];
$editdate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row["date"]));
$editimage  = $row["image"];
$editinfo  = $row["additionalinfo"];

$return = array("name" => $editname,
                  "date" => $editdate,
                  "image" => $editimage,
                  "info" => $editinfo,
                  "getid" => $_GET["editid"]); //only for debugging
```

---

**2nd EDIT**

After an extensive (but pleasant) debugging in chat... We nailed the ajax `data` mistake.

It should be :

```
data: {editid: editid}, // to have the id in $_GET['editid']
```

Comment: You're right. I corrected that. But unfortunatly it's the same result.

Comment: Ok... Now it is certainly because of `$row` scope (defined within the `while` loop. By the way, since you obviously expect only one line, that `while` is useless. Remove `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` and replace it with `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` and also remove the end curly bracket of that `while`.

Comment: I knew there must be something wrong with the loop! Sometimes the result can be so simple. But still `NULL` except the date. This is now 1970-01-01. (doesn't matter what the date was before)

Comment: mmm... Try to comment that out: `$result = $stmt->get_result();`

Comment: AJAX calls now `parsererror`. But a good way to test the `.fail` part of the request ;-)

Comment: Ha... And place `$stmt->close();` at the end... See [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19531445/2159528) about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192183/discussion-between-gepu-and-louys-patrice-bessette).

Answer (score 0):

Include the `$return[]` line inside the while loop