mysqld memory consumption is constantly growing on bulk INSERT statements
Here's the repository with all the details.
To the request of Wilson Hauck in the comments, here's a 2 hour test running the script with relevant info at a few points in time.
Essentially, we have a script that needs to fetch and transform data from some API and then insert it into the database. That data ends up being around 10-20 million lines. MySQL should have no problem dealing with that, so at first, since the script was written in Rust with sqlx, we assumed it was a problem with sqlx. So to rule that out, after having wrote this insert test script above (in the repo) in Rust, I rewrote it in Java 11 (close to what we use in production already) and the same problem occurred.
We've searched through and tried a multitude of things, from inspecting MySQL status, to tweaking various MySQL/InnoDB settings, to reducing the bulk size, to even not having a prepared statement in Java, but no matter what, the leakage is still there and linear.
Having MySQL progressively take more disk space is expected, after all we're inserting data in bulk here. But taking more RAM is definitely not, and it will end up crashing our servers if we leave mysqld do its job in this condition.
While seeking for help elsewhere, someone mentioned that InnoDB is probably using memory-mapped files, which could be a plausible explanation, but then there's a problem with the measurements themselves and I have no clue how to make them more precise to make sure it's not leaking. :(
Does anyone have any clue what could possibly be happening here?
Edit: I should mention that I also don't know if this way of inserting the data in bulk is even correct. I'm just doing something very simple, an insert in fixed-length bulks of 1000 rows. The only alternative we have is creating a dump file that does exactly the same thing. (For some reason, there's no memory problem when doing a dump.)

Try innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 in the conf file,  restart the server and insert bulk,  it will be more efficient.

What happens if you issue a COMMIT statement after every INSERT? What happens if you set innodb_buffer_pool_size to a smaller value, say, 128mb? The MariaDB fork has, in recent versions, some automation around RAM allocation.  It has to be said, it is extremely unlikely that MySQL has an actual memory leak.

All transactions are autocommitted. We did try yesterday to commit manually, had no effect.

Both innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 and innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M had no effect on the trend of the graph either.

OS, Version?
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 2 hours UPTIME running the INSERT's.  Do not stop the insert while gathering this data, please.
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE,
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,
ulimit -a       for list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
df -h  for Used - Free space by device,
df -i  for inode info by device,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

I'll try and provide all of the text results you mentioned today if you want, but the graphs I show in the repo come from Docker Desktop's Portainer extension running the mysql:8.2 image. Were you not able to reproduce the behavior?

@WilsonHauck I added a link to the 2 hour test, it's all in the GitHub repo I provided now. Since I used the Docker container though, I didn't have access to stuff like top, htop, iostat or free, but I included everything I could run nonetheless.

Will look at the repository and get back to you.

Do you know how many cores are on your 8G server?  Any SSD or NVME storage devices?  Analysis in processes.  May be a couple days due to medical appointments before configurations suggestions are posted in an Answer.

For our cloud environment, we have the following specs: vCore: 2 CPU | RAM: 4 GB | SSD: 80 GB, server is 24 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5690 @ 3.47GHz (2 Sockets).

Your meminfo indicates you have 8 G of RAM, what is your MySQL Server specs?  Any SSD or NVME on the MySQL Server?

For the information that I put on the repo, the docker container was running on my M1 MacOS machine, which has an SSD, no NVME and 16GB of RAM.
(For the cloud environment, as I said it has an SSD of 80GB.)

Suggestions to consider to accomplish more inserts per hour for your my.cnf [mysqld] section.
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 for more IOPS limit
binlog_cache_size=1M  # from 32K to reduce binlog_cache_use below 4,534 RPhr
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G  # from 128M to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads 87 RPS
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 25 percent to improve inserts per second
innodb_change_buffering=none  # from all to reduce overhead, reload from scratch
innodb_log_buffer_size=1G  # from 16M to buffer ~ 10 min before log write
innodb_log_file_size=2G  # from ~48M to reduce log rotation frequency of once a minute
innodb_old_blocks_pct=1  # from 37 percent to minimize setaside from innodb_buffer_pool_size 

there are many more opportunities to consider.

We tested with our original script, and the RAM increased as high as 10GB without ever going down after, for 900MB of data transfer. We're not looking for more performant inserts, we want mysql to not blow up its memory consumption.

Your test-2hours/readme.md indicates 10,000 rows inserted in 1h50m.  The SHOW GLOBAL STATUS provided indicates in uptime of 8,001 seconds, innodb_rows_inserted were 10,000,000.  Please review the SHOW GLOBAL STATUS com_stmt_prepare_% counters.  You should find in 8,001 seconds of uptime there were 8 com_stmt_prepares requested and 0 com_stmt_close requests.  This absence of close when the prepare is finished executing is a part of the growing RAM used and never released to release resources required when a stmt is prepared.

My bad, there was an error in the readme. I meant that it finished inserting the 10,000 bulks of 1000 rows.

com_stmt_prepare showing 8 is expected: I'm doing the same prepared request over and over again with different values so it doesn't create a new one every time. Yet there were 10,000 INSERT requests made, and the memory grows constantly on each request, so I really don't think this is where the memory growth problem comes from.

You may wish to review this posted question and answers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531195/ to minimize RAM growth over hours.
